# How can I save a image file from a String in Java?

Tags: java, regex, arrays

I need read a file, extract the bytes and add the `<segment></segment>` tag. Then I have to extract the bytes and extract what is between `<segment>` label. Finally, the tag data will be used to make an exact copy of the original image... but my problem is that the image does not look like the original.

With text files works fine but not with images.

This is my java code. Is easy:

```
public class MyFile {


public static void main(String[] args) {

     try{
     /* Read File */
        File aFile= new File("infinito.jpg");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(aFile);
        long sizeFichero = aFile.length();

        byte []datos = new byte[(int) sizeFichero];

        fis.read(datos);
        fis.close();

        /* Write copy file */
        File copyFile = new File("infinto_COPY.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(copyFile);

        /* Add bytes to array bytes */
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
        outputStream.write("<segment>".getBytes());
        outputStream.write(datos);
        outputStream.write("</segment>".getBytes());

        byte [] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

        /* Regular Expression */
        String text = new String(bytes);
        String regexpr = "<segment>(.*?)</segment>";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regexpr, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(text);

        /* If find between <segment></segment> then write file */
        if (mat.find()){

            String group1 = mat.group(1);
            fos.write(group1.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }



        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}

}
```

The result. Original and the copy:

[image: original]

[image: copy]

How could I do it by analyzing regular expression?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why would you *want* to do it with regex, first of all? Second of all, if you have plain text in XML, that's different from image data. Wouldn't you want to convert it to binary data first?

Comment: Regex is basically for text data which is String type in java. String is an array of `char`s and each `char` is comprised of two bytes. Giving the mixture of text and byte data as one unit of input to regex engine is not a good idea (IMHO), where the engine attempts to read series of `char`s.

Comment: `"string".getBytes()` and `new String(bytes)` use the default platform encoding, which is probably not compatible with treating the bytes of a JPEG as a String. For instance, JPEGs typically (not always) begin with `ff d8 ff e0` which would be completely invalid as UTF-8. Always use the overrides of `getBytes` and the `String` ctor that take an explicit encoding, and stop trying to treat binary image files as text.

Comment: Another alternative could be using Base64 encoding and decoding, I have not used them but that seems to be a workable solution. Read byte array from file and Base64 encode that to String then wrap it with `<segment>` tag. Use this String with regex to extract out content between tag. Then Base64 decode back to byte array. Try org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 or from java 8 java.util.Base64. There are loads of examples if google around.

Comment: Thank you people. Base64 saved me. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the suggestion of @madhav-turangi. I tried your code on Java 7, and used the [Apache Commons Codec library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi) to base64-encode/decode your binary data.

To make your code work, add in your import list:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Change your line:

```
outputStream.write(datos);
```

With:

```
outputStream.write(Base64.encodeBase64(datos));
```

Then change your line:

```
fos.write(group1.getBytes());
```

With:

```
fos.write(Base64.decodeBase64(group1.getBytes()));
```

The above works, as tested.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's just what I needed ^^. Sorry for the delay in responding.